# How to validate a form used for upload multiple images, in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have code to validate my file upload form: 
But it seems not working properly. 
Any help:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["file"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")


{
alert("You must select an Image or Images");
return false;
}
}
</script>
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: document.forms["myForm"]["file"] is undefined since you specify the files[] name on your input.

Answer (score 0):

Now with HTML5 you can do this :

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And then in Javascript :

```
function validateForm() {
   var x=document.forms["myForm"]["files"].value;
   if (x==null || x=="") {
      alert("You must select an Image or Images");
      return false;
   }
}
```

It works, but it should exist a better way other than the "value" attribute to retrieve all the files submitted in Javascript (returning a kind of array), however I don't find it.